# How can I pull the user name from Sys.info()?

Tags: r, windows

In the effort of making a script as flexible as possible, I'm trying to reference the username in a path automatically, i.e. `Admin` in `"C:/Users/Admin"`.

R `base`'s `Sys.info()` gives me the information I'm looking for:

```
sysname   | release | version                      | nodename          | machine  | login
"Windows" | "7 x64" | "build 7601, Service Pack 1" | "WINDOWS MACHINE" | "x86-64" | "Admin"
```

But far I've been unable to pull this as a variable/string of any kind to perform operations with.

Thanks.

Comment: Sys.info()['user'] works in Mac / OS X -- give a shot in Windows!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These things tend to be very OS-specific.  On the one I use, `Sys.getenv("USER")` works.   But it is a good idea to abstract this away -- and as luck will have it Gabor has done that for you:

```
R> whoami::username()
[1] "mynmaeonthisbox"
R>
```

The (micro-)package has a few other accessors too, and is on CRAN.

*Edit:*  As much as I like the [whoami](https://cran.r-project.org/package=whoami) package, @Joy was quite correct that the *narrow* answer to the question is to subset the object returned from `Sys.info()` -- and this will work on *any* R version without any additional packages.  So `Sys.info()["user"]`